# Vim syntax highlighting breaking for prototypes.h file due to folds. Where are folds saved?

Tags: c++, vim, syntax-highlighting, folding

When I include the line:

```
au BufWinEnter * silent! loadview "load folds
```

Which resumes my saved folds, it breaks the syntax highlighting... but only in files named specifically "prototypes.h"... which is what I always name my .h files, so it must be some saved data breaking it.

Where are folds saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated in help, used the following sequence: `:help :loadview`: “… the view stored with ":mkview" is loaded.”, then `:h :mkview` (really `<C-]>` on `:mkview` in the text): “… a name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended …”, `:h 'viewdir'` (same, `<C-]>`): “default for … and Win32: "$VIM/vimfiles/view", for Unix: "~/.vim/view"…”. I was unable to find the description of how name is generated, but simple test has shown that for `/usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/starting.txt` it generated `=+usr=+share=+vim=+vim73=+doc=+starting.txt=`.

If you want to use vim efficiently you should know how to use its help system.

Comment: Thank you! I had got about to the `:h viewdir` before getting lost, and googled. Anyway a quick rm * in that folder solved my problems : )